# What is the most aerodynamic Satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite, design, aerodynamics, drag

From what I understand at least in the lower orbits you want the least amount of drag possible.

My brain is telling me that a long pole or submarine shape satellite orientated to the direction of travel or direction of solar wind would be best and not a ball at all?

At what point does the extra weight and mass to make a satellite aerodynamic cost more fuel then saved?

Comment: Aerodynamics at a pressure of about 1 bar and subsonic speeds may be very different to drag in a nearly perfect vacuum and at hypersonic orbital speed.

Comment: @Uwe If you released 2 rubber balloons with a .2psi  from the bow of the ISS one shaped as a strait noodle balloon and the other round how much would "nearly" effect  each balloon?

Comment: At theses speed and pressure cross section is all that matter.

Comment: Parachutes are intentional extremely non-aerodynamic. A well-designed parachute has a drag coefficient in the lower atmosphere a bit less than 2.  In the thermosphere, that same parachute's drag coefficient might increase to 2.4. Aircraft are intentionally extremely aerodynamic. A well-designed aircraft can have a drag coefficient as low as 0.02, a hundredth the parachute's. In the thermosphere, that same aircraft's coefficient of drag will increase to over 2 -- more than that of the parachute in the lower atmosphere. Shape doesn't matter much in space. Nothing is aerodynamic in space.

Comment: @DavidHammen so the space plane below is not in space?

Comment: That's not a space plane, @Muze. It would have been a flying brick in the atmosphere. And at 250 km altitude, it was barely in space. The primary driver for the shape was the need for a sizable area for non-moving solar panels.

Comment: @DavidHammen I know just messing with you. Happy New year!

Comment: Some like of low orbit satellite. E.g. Kosmos 954 or nuclear satellite in general. The only motivation to go with nuclear power is to improve aerodynamics.

Comment: This has inspired [Technological challenges to sending a high altitude balloon to space and orbit from 50 km?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49374/12102)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The only satellite I know of that was shaped to have low drag was [GOCE](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-operational-eo-missions/goce), which [orbited at 250 km.](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Observing_the_Earth/GOCE/Satellite)

> Since it was vital to ensure that the measurements taken are of true gravity and not influenced by any movement of the satellite, this unique five-metre long arrow-shaped satellite had none of the moving parts often seen in other spacecraft. The satellite, together with its instrumentation, actually forms a single composite gravity-measuring device.
>
> The satellite orbited Earth as low as possible to observe the strongest possible gravity-field signal – hence GOCE was designed to skim the edge of Earth's atmosphere at a height of about 250 km. Low fuel consumption meant that its altitude could be lowered to 235 km in 2012.
>
> An electric ion thruster at the back of the satellite continuously generated tiny forces to compensate for any drag that GOCE experienced along its orbit.
>
> The need to fly low and be ultra-stable led to a novel satellite design that minimised air drag and torque and excludes mechanical disturbances. The result was a slim 5 metre-long satellite with a cross sectional area of about 1m2, weighing in at about 1050 kg. The satellite was symmetrical about its horizontal plane and had two winglets that provided additional aerodynamic stability.

[image: GOCE]

You can see this places constraints on the satellite's shape: you can't have protruding solar panels, antennas etc. This means it's only done when really necessary; for most purposes it's much cheaper to go to a slightly higher orbit instead.

Comment: That's very cool and new to me.

Comment: The solar panels are built into it as shown and an antenna follows the wings. The space craft is on a lean performing a turn the belly facing towards the camera.

Comment: @Muze Sorry about that... try: [GRACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Recovery_and_Climate_Experiment)

Comment: that question's closed, but once you get down to 120 km or so, drag becomes too high to stay in orbit (you'll reenter in less than 1 orbit)

Comment: Fin stabilizers, in orbit? Neat, it's literally a spaceplane.