# How many existing satellites have a continuously varying orbit because of human design decisions?

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbital-maneuver, solar-sail, advanced-propulsion, science

In the space community, there is an assumption that changes to an Earth satellite's orbit are infrequent (other than those due to atmospheric drag).  Are there any known [satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail#Satellites) designed to continuously change their orbits using solar sails or another inexpensive propulsion method?

By continuous, I do not refer to "station-keeping" maneuvers which are in fact designed to maintain a specific orbit.  I refer instead to satellites which purposely change their orbits continuously, by design.

EDIT:  By satellite, I mean an earth-orbiting object designed to avoid atmospheric re-entry for multiple years, doing something besides just adjusting its orbit during that time (i.e., its purpose is more than just to demonstrate the feasibility of a continuously changing orbit).

EDIT: Title changed to "How many existing satellites have a continuously varying orbit because of human design decisions?"

Comment: I mean, there's the X-37b.

Comment: https://secure.planetary.org/site/SPageNavigator/mission_control.html

Comment: GOCE continuously thrusted to *maintain*, not *change* its orbit. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33202/6944

Comment: Title says "powered" but question includes "using solar sails" which don't require power *per se* at least not from the spacecraft, though a little power is needed to maintain attitude. cf. [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37851/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23512/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37118/12102). Should "powered" be removed from the title?

Comment: @user25876 once the X-37b reaches space and settles down from launch, does it undergo powered movement for any reason other than to maintain a semblance of stable orbit and/or re-enter Earth's atmosphere?

Comment: @user12102 great suggestion, I implemented it.  This question is getting harder and harder to ask clearly.

Comment: It seems like any satellite in an orbit with a substantial amount of precession would be a valid answer to the question as it is right now.

Comment: @user12024 the orbit's precession is a part of what station-keeping maneuvers try to make stable for most satellites.  The stability of the parameters is what I am defining as the realization of a stable orbit.  The magnitude of the precession, as long as it is not changing by design, is just another orbital parameter for a fixed orbit (which does not really exist due to atmospheric drag, solar pressure, etc. but I am asking whether people design satelllites on purpose to undergo constant orbital parameter adjustments rather than trying to keep them stable).

Comment: @brethvoice Yep. It carries a significant amount of fuel for orbital maneuvering (an early proposal offered ~3km/s delta-V; later estimates suggest 500-1000 m/s depending on payload mass) on a hypergolic bipropellant thruster, and has also apparently been configured as a testbed for other engine technologies (e.g. Hall thrusters).

Comment: @brethvoice a follow-on to [my earlier question about the use of "powered" and "solar sail"](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53753/#comment175452_53753), there are groups of satellites that have adjusted their attitude to make their solar panels interact with weak atmospheric drag to either drift slowly forward  or backward over time compared to their nominal attitude in order to spread out within their orbital plane after being launched and deployed together. I'm still looking forward to a clarification from you on exactly will or won't count as "powered".

Comment: @brethvoice in the drag example, all orbital parameters of the those spacecraft will be the same *except epoch* or time at which they reach their ascending node. It's also called "phasing". But if you really intend "powered" to mean thrust via reaction mass of some kind being pushed via use of power by the spacecraft continuously to do something more than compensating for drag to maintain an orbit, I have a hunch that the answer is no, at least for the ones we know about :-)

Comment: @uhoh your assumptions about what "powered" means are correct.  You were able to read between the lines and answer my actual question...but I do not believe I have enough experience and knowledge in this field to post an actual answer vs. responding to your comment which I find valuable and helpful.

Comment: @brethvoice then I've written an answer based on our discussion, let me know if it does your question justice, or if there needs to be changes. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also answers to [What technologies enable or at least help satellite operation in Very Low Earth Orbit (VLEO)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50905/12102)

---

If:

- "powered" means "thrust via reaction mass of some kind being pushed via use of power by the spacecraft continuously, and
- "a continuously varying orbit" means continuously actively altering it's otherwise natural orbit (which already continuously varies due to several effects)

and [it seems that they do](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53753/how-many-existing-satellites-have-a-continuously-varying-orbit-because-of-human?noredirect=1#comment175667_53753), then the answer to "How many existing satellites..." *is probably zero.*

@OrganicMarble [points out](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53753/how-many-existing-satellites-have-a-continuously-varying-orbit-because-of-human?noredirect=1#comment175437_53753) that:

> GOCE continuously thrusted to maintain, not change its orbit.

and links to [this answer to *What is the most aerodynamic Satellite?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33202/12102)

I [mentioned](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53753/how-many-existing-satellites-have-a-continuously-varying-orbit-because-of-human?noredirect=1#comment175575_53753) that:

> ...there are groups of satellites that have adjusted their attitude to make their solar panels interact with weak atmospheric drag to either drift slowly forward or backward over time compared to their nominal attitude in order to spread out within their orbital plane after being launched and deployed together. I'm still looking forward to a clarification from you on exactly will or won't count as "powered".

and now remember, I was thinking of the CYGNSS constellation. From [How can the CYGNSS spacecrafts (actually) measure ocean roughness?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19007/12102):

> [image: CYGNSS]
>
> **above:** screen shots from [CYGNSS_FactSheet_October2014](http://clasp-research.engin.umich.edu/missions/cygnss/docs/CYGNSS_FactSheet_October2014.pdf)

They did use a little electrical power to perform attitude adjustments to increase or decrease atmospheric drag mostly from the solar panels, but it was not powered flight.

From [this answer to *Rocket to launch 8 cubesat to LEO at an equidistant distance*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41954/12102):

> > Here is an example of *a simulation* of the use of alternating between high and low drag configurations to achieve equal spaced phasing and then to maintain it using small station-keeping drag adjustments:
>
> [image: Figure 8: Time-discretized high-drag commands are assigned to achieve desired slots (b) with commands]
>
> > Figure 8: Time-discretized high-drag commands are assigned to achieve desired slots (b) with commands
>
> [image: Figure 9: Attitude modes of Dove satellite enable large drag area ratios (a) Orthographic projections with cross-sectional areas. (b) High-drag and low-drag attitudes]
>
> > Figure 9: Attitude modes of Dove satellite enable large drag area ratios (a) Orthographic projections with cross-sectional areas. (b) High-drag and low-drag attitudes

#### But I could be wrong!

If someone thinks of something that meets your criteria, or something new is put in space that does, then new answers can be posted.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer nor can it be considered "powered", but [this page](https://webapps.itc.utwente.nl/sensor/default.aspx?view=allsatellites) from [The University of Twente](https://www.utwente.nl/) lists about 235 satellites that are in [sun-synchronous orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit).

A sun-synchronous orbit is a nearly-polar orbit carefully calculated to use Earth's equatorial bulge to adjust the satellite's orbit by about one degree per day. Since the angle to the sun also changes by about one degree per day, this keeps the sun at the same angle to the satellite's orbit all year long.

This is useful for scientific satellites that perform long-term observations of the sun, or satellites that don't have any on-board batteries and therefore can't tolerate having Earth shadow their solar panels.

It represents a continuous change in the *Keplerian* orbital elements due to a non-central force (Earth's oblateness), albeit completely natural in origin.

Comment: I consider changes to orbital parameters from things like gravitational field irregularities, atmospheric drag, etc. all things that designers could have predicted and accounted for.  I am continually impressed by the ingenuity of the human race though, and the technological prowess referred to in this answer is one more convincing piece of evidence for me.

Comment: *Good point!* I added a few finer points, please feel free to edit further.